# Local Home requires POSIX when deploying Bitbucket on AKS using azurefile csi

Tags: bitbucket, posix, azure-aks, azure-files, csi-driver

I am deploying Bitbucket to AKS cluster following the Atlassian installation guide: [Install Atlassian DC Helm Charts](https://atlassian.github.io/data-center-helm-charts/userguide/INSTALLATION/) and using [azurefile-csi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-csi#dynamically-create-azure-files-pvs-by-using-the-built-in-storage-classes) to dynamically create both PV and PVC for local home.

After deploying the helm chart, the pod with Bitbucket starts but never gets to a ready state due to the following error:

```
2024-01-08 17:52:21,922 ERROR [spring-startup]  c.a.j.s.w.s.JohnsonDispatcherServlet SpringMVC dispatcher [springMvc] could not be started


org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 

 Error creating bean with name 'meshHealthcheck' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/atlassian/bitbucket/app/WEB-INF/lib/bitbucket-git-mesh-8.9.8.jar!/com/atlassian/stash/internal/scm/git/mesh/MeshHealthcheck.class]:

 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 

 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 

 Error creating bean with name 'meshClient' defined in com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.GitWiring$MeshWiring: 

 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'meshClient' parameter 2; 

 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 

 Error creating bean with name 'routePropagatingClientInterceptor' defined in com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.GitWiring$MeshWiring: 

 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'routePropagatingClientInterceptor' parameter 0; 

 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 

 Error creating bean with name 'meshRouter' defined in com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.GitWiring$MeshWiring: 

 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'meshRouter' parameter 5; 

 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

 Error creating bean with name 'sidecarManager': 

 Invocation of init method failed; 

 nested exception is java.nio.file.FileSystemException: 

 /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/mesh/config/control-plane.pem:

 Operation not permitted

 ...

 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)

 ... 5 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/mesh/config/control-plane.pem: Operation not permitted

 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)

 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)

 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)

 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setMode(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:254)

 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setPermissions(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:276)

 at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2080)

 at com.atlassian.bitbucket.mesh.util.KeyUtils.write(KeyUtils.java:382)

 at com.atlassian.bitbucket.mesh.util.KeyUtils.writePublicKey(KeyUtils.java:260)

 at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.mesh.MeshLauncher.start(MeshLauncher.java:121)

 at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.mesh.DefaultSidecarManager.startSidecar(DefaultSidecarManager.java:272)

 at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.mesh.DefaultSidecarManager.internalStart(DefaultSidecarManager.java:223)

 at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.mesh.DefaultSidecarManager.start(DefaultSidecarManager.java:178)

 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

 ... 5 common frames omitted
```

When checking the stack trace I realized that the error:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/mesh/config/control-plane.pem: Operation not permitted
```

is being thrown when executing:

```
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2080)
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.mesh.util.KeyUtils.write(KeyUtils.java:382)

 at com.atlassian.bitbucket.mesh.util.KeyUtils.writePublicKey(KeyUtils.java:260)

 at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.mesh.MeshLauncher.start(MeshLauncher.java:121)

 at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.mesh.DefaultSidecarManager.startSidecar(DefaultSidecarManager.java:272)

 at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.mesh.DefaultSidecarManager.internalStart(DefaultSidecarManager.java:223)

 at com.atlassian.stash.internal.scm.git.mesh.DefaultSidecarManager.start(DefaultSidecarManager.java:178)
```

For Local Home I am dynamically creating both pv and pvc using the built in storage class azurefile-csi from Dynamically create azure files.

For local home I am passing the follow values on *values.yaml*

```
localHome:

# Dynamic provisioning of local-home using the K8s Storage Classes
#
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic
# https://atlassian.github.io/data-center-helm-charts/examples/storage/aws/LOCAL_STORAGE/
#
persistentVolumeClaim:

# -- If 'true', then a 'PersistentVolume' and 'PersistentVolumeClaim' will be dynamically
# created for each pod based on the 'StorageClassName' supplied below.
#
create: true

# -- Specify the name of the 'StorageClass' that should be used for the local-home
# volume claim.
#
storageClassName: "azurefile-csi"

# -- Specifies the standard K8s resource requests and/or limits for the local-home
# volume claims.
#
resources:
requests:
storage: 1Gi
```

I also tried to create a claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
name: pvc-local-home
namespace: bitbucket
spec:
accessModes:
- ReadWriteMany
storageClassName: "azurefile-csi" 
resources:
requests:
storage: 1Gi
```

and pass it as:

```
localHome:

# Dynamic provisioning of local-home using the K8s Storage Classes
#
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic
# https://atlassian.github.io/data-center-helm-charts/examples/storage/aws/LOCAL_STORAGE/
#
persistentVolumeClaim:

# -- If 'true', then a 'PersistentVolume' and 'PersistentVolumeClaim' will be dynamically
# created for each pod based on the 'StorageClassName' supplied below.
#
create: false

...

# -- Static provisioning of local-home using K8s PVs and PVCs
#
# NOTE: Due to the ephemeral nature of pods this approach to provisioning volumes for
# pods is not recommended. Dynamic provisioning described above is the prescribed
# approach.
#
# When 'persistentVolumeClaim.create' is 'false', then this value can be used to define
# a standard K8s volume that will be used for the local-home volume(s). If not defined,
# then an 'emptyDir' volume is utilised. Having provisioned a 'PersistentVolume', specify
# the bound 'persistentVolumeClaim.claimName' for the 'customVolume' object.
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#static
#
customVolume:
 persistentVolumeClaim:
 claimName: "pvc-local-home"
```

Both resulted in the same error shown above.

Bitbucket has issues when trying to set **POSIX** in Azure Files as **Azure files CSI** is not compliant with **POSIX**, for that an **NFS File Share** has to be used.

When running the helm install using emptyDir for local home the issue does not happen.

I couldn't find any mention of **POSIX** in the section 5 Configure Persistent Storage of the installation guide.

Am I doing something wrong or a volume compliant with **POSIX** is needed in order to run Bitbucket properly on Kubernetes and that was not mentioned anywhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Files, lacks full POSIX compliance, you can switch to using Azure Disks or set up an NFS server. Azure Disks are more POSIX-compliant but can only be mounted to a single node, making them suitable for single-node setups while setting up an NFS server allows for multi-node access while maintaining POSIX compliance.
Follow the [guide](https://atlassian.github.io/data-center-helm-charts/userguide/INSTALLATION/), please modify the persistence section inside the values.yaml which you got from helm get values bitbucket -n .  with the Azure disk details

```
persistence:
  localHome:
    enabled: true
    storageClassName: "your AzureDiskstorageclass"
    size: "10Gi"
  sharedHome:
    enabled: true
    storageClassName: "your AzureDiskstorageclass"
    size: "20Gi"
```

After that, deploy bitbucket.

```
helm install bitbucket atlassian-data-center/bitbucket --namespace default --values values.yaml
```

[image]

```
kubectl get pods
```

[image]

You can also try setting up [NFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-nfs-volume) and accordingly update the
bitbucket's values.yaml file to reference to the NFS

```
localHome:
  customVolume:
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: bitbucket-nfs-pvc
```

and then redeploy bitbucket using
`helm upgrade <release-name> atlassian-data-center/bitbucket --namespace <namespace> --values values.yaml`

Reference document:
[Bitbucket Setup Guide](https://atlassian.github.io/data-center-helm-charts/userguide/INSTALLATION/)
[NFS for Bitbucket](https://atlassian.github.io/data-center-helm-charts/examples/storage/nfs/NFS/)